# Como elimino un elemento anterior a otro en una lista en Python?

Tags: python

Necesito encontrar un método que me permita eliminar el elemento anterior a otro en una lista.
Por ejemplo, si tomara la lista:

```
a= ["rojo","verde","azul","e","amarillo","naranja","e","violeta"]
```

Tomando `"e"` como el parámetro, y teniendo que eliminar el valor anterior, debería eliminar los elementos `"e", "azul" y "naranja"`, manteniendo el resto.

Podrían ayudarme?

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora para lograrlo?

Comment: No hay nada built-in en Python para lograr algo así, pero puedes hacerlo tu mismo con un bucle for.

Comment: Se me olvidó aclarar que para ayudarte deberías demostrar que intentaste hacerlo por tu cuenta. Ya que si te doy una respuesta con eso hecho, te perderías la oportunidad de aprender por tu cuenta.

Comment: Tengo un bucle for, y dentro del bucle un if para identificar el parámetro, el "e". Pero no tengo claro que método usar para remover el item anterior de la lista sin eliminar todo

Comment: Por cierto, podrías agregar el código que mencionas en la pregunta por favor?

Comment: Mmmm, me acabo de dar cuenta de algo. Olvida lo que dije antes (ya borré el comentario). Solamente agrega el código que tienes hecho e intentaré dar una respuesta en base a eso.

Comment: Bueno yo no aguanto una preguntas en Python por que me encanta programar en Python.... déjame ayudarte pero en esta comunidad veo que hay reglas que seguir con respecto a las preguntas... una guía para alumbrar tu mente: debes recorrer la lista naturalmente.... usa un ciclo para moverte dentro de la lista.
cuando encuentres tu objetivo... puedes apuntar al índice o posición anterior de la lista y eliminarlo, luego continuar recorriendo la lista hasta completarlo. ojo si va a usar un ciclo for usa también la funcion range para que así apuntes a los índices mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer en una sola línea:

```
def elimina(lista, valor):
    return [*[lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i+1] != valor != lista[i]], lista[-1]]
```

#### Explicación

```
[lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i+1] != valor != lista[i]]
```

es una comprensión de lista condicional: el elemento de `lista` se agrega a la lista en construcción sólo si el elemento y el siguiente son distintos de "e".

Notese que esta comprensión no copia el último elemento. Para incluirlo, haremos una nueva lista, incluyendo la comprensión y el elemento que falta:

```
[[lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i+1] != valor != lista[i]], lista[-1]]
```

Esto casi funciona, produciendo:

```
[['rojo', 'verde', 'amarillo'], 'violeta']
```

Para extraer los elementos de la sublista e incorporarlo directo en la lista principal, le agrego un asterisco por delante a la comprensión,

```
return [*[lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i+1] != valor != lista[i]], lista[-1]]
```

**Demo**

```
a= ["rojo","verde","azul","e","amarillo","naranja","e","violeta"]

def elimina(lista, valor):
    return [[lista[i] for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i+1] != valor != lista[i]], lista[-1]]

print(elimina(a, "e"))
```

produce:

```
['rojo', 'verde', 'amarillo', 'violeta']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que quieres es mejor usar el método `pop()` (aunque también usaré `remove()`) el cual elimina un elemento en base a su índice, y para obtener el índice podemos usar el método `index()`

```py
a= ["rojo","verde","azul","e","amarillo","naranja","e","violeta"]
for _ in range(a.count("e")): #uteramos segun las veces que aparezca en la lista
    i = a.index("e") #encontramos su indice
    a.pop(i-1) #eliminamos el elemento anterioir
    #en caso el elemento esté en la primera posicion se elimina el ultimo elemento de la lista
    # si no quieres eso, puedes reemplazar lo anterior por:
    # if i >0: a.pop(i-1) 
    a.remove("e") #eliminamos el elemento e
print(a)
```

**resultado**

```
['rojo', 'verde', 'amarillo', 'violeta']
```

Ten en cuenta que al obtener el índice y hay elementos repetidos, solo devuelve el primero y en caso no exista tal elemento lanzara un error, aunque eso esta un poco controlado con el `for` ya que si no existe ese elemento el `count` será 0 y no se ejecutará el `for`.

Comment: El problema con esta estrategia es que recorre la lista varias veces con tal de encontrar el proximo elemento.

Comment: @DanteS. solo recorre la lista las veces que exista tal elemento, en este caso solo lo hace 2 veces

Comment: Es verdad. y una tercera vez para saber cuantas veces aparece e.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto! Muchisimas muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: @DanteS. aun sigue siendo mejor que recorrer toda la lista en busca de coincidencias

Comment: Puede ser, no soy experto. Pero supongo que es más lento. Pero no importa, dejemoslo así. Yo solo señalaba un detalle importante.

Comment: @RocioBisang de nada, como consejo añade tu intento a la pregunta, ya que aun no los añadido.

Comment: @DanteS. mm.. ok, igual puedes dar una respuesta si consideras que hay algo mejor

Comment: Me llama la atención que el OP te haya quitado la tilde de mejor respuesta. El tema es que mi forma tiene un condicional complejo...

Comment: @DanteS. a mi también. Bueno como diría abulafia, *complejo es mejor que complicado*

Comment: Cuidado con un primer elemento "e" , por que el índice va a ser -1 y va a eliminar el último de la lista.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias ya lo edité, sin embargo eso depende de lo que quiera el OP

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy simple es usar comprensión de listas para generar una nueva lista con las condiciones que mencionas:

- Eliminar el elemento "e"
- Eliminar el elemento anterior a "e"

---

```
a_new = [e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i not in [y for x in [(i, i -1) for i, e in enumerate(a) if e == "e"] for y in x if y >= 0]]

print(a_new)
['rojo', 'verde', 'amarillo', 'violeta']
```

A priori, hay que reconocerlo, no parece una sintaxis fácil de entender:

- `[(i, i -1) for i, e in enumerate(a) if e == "e"]` esto genera una lista de tuplas con el índice del elemento `"e"` y el anterior
- `[y for x in ... for y in x if y >= 0]]` convertimos la lista de tuplas anterior en una lista simple con todos los índices, menos aquellos que sean negativos, el caso que el primer elemento de la lista se `e`
- Por último `[e for i, e in enumerate(a) if i not in ...]` generamos la nueva lista sin los elementos que definimos borrar.